# Webpack prints "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression" warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to migrate to webpack v5. I've updated a lot of dependencies. The project works for the most part, but one component is causing problems.

It prints following warnings in the console:

`[webpack-dev-server] WARNING in ./src/core/atoms/Svg.tsx 34:124-134 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

Svg.tsx:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

export interface SvgProps {
  height?: string | number;
  width?: string | number;
  className?: string;
  name: string;
}

export const Svg = ({ name, width, height, className }: SvgProps) => {
  const Component = lazy(() =>
    import(`../../assets/svg/${name}.svg`).catch((err) => {
      console.error(`Svg ${name} not found`);
    })
  );
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div style={{ width, height }}></div>}>
      <>
        <Component className={className} height={height} width={width} name={name} />
      </>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

- webpack: 5.79.0,
- webpack-dev-server: 4.13.3,
- babel/preset-env: 7.21.4,
- babel/preset-react: 7.18.6,
- babel/preset-typescript: 7.21.4,
- babel/helpers: 7.21.0,

Recently I installed babel, to be able to use storybook. I think it has to do something to do with it. Anyone have any idea what could be going on?